# Confused as to why one piece of code works and the other doesn't. Could someone help clear things up?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

Bear with me as I'm faily new to coding and I know this might be obvious to a lot of people here. Basically, I had to create code that would identify a prime number and return true in that scenario and false if not. Now, in my head both pieces of code makes sense, but apparently one works and one doesn't. Just wondering why

This is the failing code, specifically for the number 15 when it goes through the fucntion. What confuses me is why the code wouldn't just return false and end the loop for 15, since 15 % 3 === 0

```
function checkIsPrime(num) {

   
if (num === 1) {
   return false
} 
for(let i = 2; i < num ; i++){

  if (num % i == 0) {
    return false
  }   else {
    return true
  }
  }
}
```

This piece of code worked, with the differene being adding return true at the end instead of after an else condition:

```
function checkIsPrime(num) {

   
if (num === 1) {
   return false
} 
for(let i = 2; i < num ; i++){

  if (num % i == 0) {
    return false
  }   
  }
  return true
}
```

I've tried doing it whilst declaring a variable and that seemed to work too. I did this by setting a new variable at the top of the code (let answer = true) and then changing it to false under each condition where the number wasn't prime, then 'return answer' at the end. However, adding an else condition to the second if statement seemed to bring back errors again. So basically, I know how to solve it, but I feel like its more important to know *why* it works and why the other scenarios dont.

Comment: Don't post images of code, [ask]

Comment: First, tag your question either Java or JavaScript because it is likely one or the other, not both, and no sense in getting folks who follow the other tag coming to the your question. Also, please don't post your code on this site as an image but rather as code-formatted text since none of us can copy, paste and run an image.  For more on this, please see [Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/522444). Also please check out the [ask] for more on-site best-practices.

Comment: OK, the images show that you're asking about JavaScript, not Java, and so I have taken the liberty of removing the tag, but you'll still want to [edit] and improve this question if a decent answer is important to you. Else, the question risks being closed.

Comment: Run the code in your debugger and you will immediately understand the problem.

Comment: Also, you will want learn to do mental walk-throughs of your code, asking yourself "does this code make sense?" and "what is this code currently doing?" as you walk through it -- also known as "[Rubber Duck Debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)". This will also show you quickly the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. So I've gone through it for a while - am I correct in thinking the reason why the first code doesn't work is because after returning false, it carries on looping due to both return statements being inside the for loop? Also, what kind of debugger should I use? This is my 3rd day coding so haven't used one yet.

Comment: Most JavaScript engines have their own, great debugger. Every modern browser has browser dev tools with a debugger. You don't need additional tools.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your failing example both of the `if` branches result in `return`. There is no chance that the `for` loop will continue after the `if`.

You are only doing one iteration, because `return` statement will end the function (together with the `for` loop) and return given value.

I also believe your wrong formatting is what misleads you:

```js
function checkIsPrime(num) {

   
if (num === 1) {
   return false
} 
for(let i = 2; i < num ; i++){

  if (num % i == 0) {
    return false
  }   
  }             // <-- this is the end of for loop
  return true   // <-- this is executed after the whole for loop
}               // <-- this is the end of the function body
```

Ideally, you code should like something like this, so that it is more readable:

**Working example:**

```js
function checkIsPrime(num) { 
   if (num === 1) {
      return false
   } 
   for (let i = 2; i < num ; i++) {
      if (num % i === 0) {
         return false
      }   
   }             
   return true
}
```

**Non-working example:**

```js
function checkIsPrime(num) { 
   if (num === 1) {
      return false
   } 
   for (let i = 2; i < num ; i++) {
      if (num % i === 0) {
         return false
      } else {
         return true
      }
   }             
}
```

Now you should be able to cleary see the semantical difference of those two.

Comment: I would also strongly recommend you format your code, so that it is - at least - somewhat readable. It will be very useful to you and others who you will share the code with.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!! That really helped to clear it up. So basically, my for loop just returns true at the first iteration for 15 since 15 % 2 !== 0, then the function ends. Is that correct? Also, in terms of formatting code, what is good practice? Adding  // quotes to explain what each part of the code is doing I presume?

Comment: @Nick Yes, you are correct. In terms of formatting code you should try to indent your code and do some proper lining. I will edit my previous response with snippet how your code should ideally look like. The comments were used just to hint you what is going on.

Comment: Thanks again. That looks way tidier and helps to visualise the loops etc as well. Appreciate the help